# Solution to the differential equation $ \langle \nabla g(X), \overline{\nabla g(X)} \rangle =-\frac{\partial g(X)}{\partial x_{1}} $?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes

If $ \vec{u} $ (respectively $ \vec{v} $) is an element of $ \mathbb{C}^{n} $ with components $ u_{i} $ (respectively $ v_{i} $) and $ \langle \vec{u},\vec{v} \rangle $ is the Hermitian inner product $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} u_{i} \overline{v_{i}} $, then does anyone know a form for solutions of the PDE $ \langle \nabla g(X), \overline{\nabla g(X)} \rangle = -\frac{\partial g(X)}{\partial x_{1}} $ for a polynomial function $ g(X): \mathbb{C}^{n} \to \mathbb{C} $?  Is such a solution unique up to addition of a constant in $ \mathbb{C} $?  For any such solution does $ \frac{\partial g(X)}{\partial x_{1}} $ equal zero?

Comment: What are the range and domain of the function $g$?

Comment: But the solution shouldn't be unique, since if $g$ is a solution to the PDE, then so is $g + C$ for any constant. Are you prescribing some sort of boundary condition?

Comment: Thank you @WillieWong.  I corrected the statement of the problem to state that $ g(X): \mathbb{C}^{n} \to \mathbb{C} $ is a polynomial in $ n $-indeterminates $ x_{1},\dots,x_{n} $ and that I consider a solution $ g(X) $ to be equivalent to one of the form $ g(X)+c $ where $ c \in \mathbb{C} $.

Comment: I don't know the most general form of the solution. 

But, observe that if $k\in \mathbb{C}^n$, then 
$$ g(X) = \sum_{j = 1}^n k_j x_j $$
solves the PDE iff (I almost got caught out by the double conjugate)
$$ \sum_{j = 1}^n k_j^2 = - k_1 $$
This defines a variety in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and shows that there are infinitely solutions _just under this ansatz_. When $n \geq 3$ there are also multiple solutions with $k_1 = 0$.